# Outlook add-in Web version Office.context.mailbox keeps returning error code 9020

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Every time I called `Office.context.mailbox` keeps returning error code 9020. I see in some articles that the error was fixed but I didn't anyone saying what was the source of the issue. How may I avoid this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync returns error 9020 An internal error has occured](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/926) page:

> This issue was reported for OWA and the fix went in OWA client.

If you still have got the same error I'd suggest posting/file a bug on the `office-js` repo on github.